# why tkinter button is not visible while running the code?

Tags: python, tkinter

button is not visible while executing the program

```
def frame1():
    # label(text displayed on the frame1)

    label1 = Label(root,text="Welcome to DeciTree!\n\nThis is a desktop GUI app written in Python \nthat builds a predictive model \nusing a Decision tree algorithm called ID3\n\nClick NEXT to continue ",
                   anchor=CENTER, height=14, width=70, background='light green')
    label1.config(font=('comic sans', 38, 'bold'))
    label1.pack()

    # button(next button on frame1)
    button1 = Button(root, text="NEXT", height=30,width=30, command=frame2)
    button1.config(font=('comic sans',20,'bold'))
    button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

Comment: Can you add a complete and executable example of code that exhibits the problem you are having? What you have shared so far isn't complete and doesn't allow anyone to help you fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see all of the code but have you closed it off with `root.mainloop()`? and if so, does it print the labels? Do you get a crash report? Maybe you have to `root.update()` your program to display the button? Do you have a big enough area to display the button? Does `frame2` work properly?